# Did Mordechai wear the bigdei kehuna?

Tags: sources-mekorot, purim, megillat-esther, mordechai

Are there ANY sources that say that Mordechai wore the levush kohen gadol?

Comment: Haven't you asked this question already?

Comment: It didn't have any engagement, i am trying again with a more general approach. looking for any possible source that may mention this.

Comment: So why don't you just edit the original question?

Comment: @TheTargum I like your enthousiasm, but on Mi yodeya, if you have a question that gets no answers or any engagement, you should not start a new topic. Just edit your question if necessary, start a bounty etc...

Comment: @Shmuel Ah, okay. thank you for clarifying that.

Comment: Mordechai was from the tribe of Binyamin, not a Kohen. The Bais Hamikdash had been destroyed before he came to Bavel. For both reasons he could not wear the Bigdei Kehuna.

Answer (score 1):

According to Rav Aharon Friedman Rosh HaYeshiva of Keren B'Yavneh, as quoted [here](https://www.kby.org/hebrew/torat-yavneh/view.asp?id=4333)

> בשעה שביקש הקב"ה להודיע לישראל על נצחונם הגדול העתיד לבוא, נתן בליבו של המן לבקש לעצמו לבוש מלכות אשר לבש בו המלך, המורכב מתכלת, חור וארגמן ויש בו עטרת זהב והוא מזכיר לכל רואיו את בגדי הכהן הגדול. חזר הקב"ה והעביר את הלבושים למרדכי גדולם של ישראל, ושוב חזר מרדכי ולבש בגדי כהונה ומלכות כשיצא בשלום מלפני המלך לאחר חתימת אגרותיו ושליחתם, ככהן היוצא מן הקודש לאחר קבלת תפילותיו.‏

Based on the Medrash the Achashverosh wore the "levush kohen gadol" at his feast.

When Homon requested for "the one who finds favor in the king's eyes" to wear the royal garments, he was referring to the "levush kohen gadol" the king wore many years earlier.

Since he was granted this wish, he then had to dress Mordechai in these garments, thus Mordechai wore them during the *horse-parade* and subsequent signing of the "new letters".

Comment: He starts by calling them "לבוש מלכות ... והוא מזכיר לכל רואיו את בגדי הכהן הגדול". So not actual *bidgei kehuna*, but special royal clothing that resembled the *bidgei kehuna*.